# How to do get complex return structures with dict.get() method?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary A. If b is in A, then A['b'] is of type string. Is there a way to write the following code using the dict.get() method ? Or is there a more elegant way to rewrite the following code ?

```
dict_B = []
if key in dict_A:
    dict_B.append(dict_A[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

```
#the way you did it but with get()
dict_A = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
wanted_key='b'
dict_B=[]
if wanted_key in dict_A: 
    dict_B.append(dict_A.get(wanted_key))
print(dict_B)
#>>> [2]

#2. Option; a list comprehnsion
dict_B=[dict_A.get(key) for key in dict_A if key == 'b']
print(dict_B)
#>>> [2]
```